# How to access response of callback from AWS Lambda function in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple `AWS Lambda function` which returns the `id` of the user when he logins.

```
if (event.email && password) 
        {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM doctor_data WHERE doc_email = ?", [event.email], function(error, results, fields)
            
            {
                connection.release();

                if(results.length > 0)
                {
                    bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function(err, ress)
                    {
                      if(!ress)
                        {

                        callback (null, "Incorrect Password");
                        }
                      else
                        {   
                            callback (null, results[0].doc_id);
                        }
                    });         
                }
                else
                {
                callback (null, "Incorrect Email");
                }
        
            });
        
        }
        
        else 
        
        {
            callback(null, "Please enter Email and Password!");
        }
```

Now in Android (Java) we used the below mentioned logic for accessing the id. We directly store it in the String variable and it works fine.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

String responseMsg = response.body().string();
Log.e(TAG, msg: responseMsg+ " responseMsg");
```

The `iOS swift` code is mentioned below.

```
 func callingLoginAPI(login: LoginModel,completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, String) -> ()){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        .contentType("application/json")
        ]
        
        AF.request(doctor_login, method: .post, parameters: login, encoder: 
            JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).response{
            response in debugPrint(response)
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                let urlString = doctor_login
                guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
                                
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, err) in
                    guard let data = data else {return}
                    let dataAsString = String(data: data,encoding: .utf8)
                    print("this is", dataAsString)
                    do{
                     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
                    print(json)
                    print("json")
                }
                    catch{
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            completionHandler(false, "Login not Done")
                            print("not done")
                        }
                }.resume()
                
                
    
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                {
                    
                    completionHandler(true, "Login Done")
                    print("done")
                }
                else{
                    completionHandler(false, "Please try again")
                    print("not done")
                }
                
               
            case.failure(let err):
                print("that")
                print(err.localizedDescription)
               completionHandler(false, "Try Again")
            }
        }
```

It's giving me the following response. It's giving me the `id` of the user which is `2` in this case but I don't know how to `get/extract` or `save` it.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to `get/extract` or `save` the `response` of the `body` which is `2` in this case?

In `Android` we used the `okhttp library` for accessing the `API` whereas in `iOS swift` we used `NSURLConnection library` for acccessing the `API`.

Comment: That nefarious "missing authentication token" message normally means the url or method to access the api ia wrong.   Its super not useful. Dpuble check the url youre accessing the API through.

Comment: @Dave URL is perfectly alright. If you notice the the `body` part it's correctly returning the `id`. What I need to know is how can I save the `id`?